# what may be the reason of RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar multiply?

Tags: python, runtime, warnings

I am usign a large library feeding it with the measured data.
Logs show that in some cases there is some error/warning message and shows the line in which this warning occurs.

Warning:

> .../MLE_funcs.py:4682:
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar multiply

Here it is:

```
y = (np.pi/2) * x * np.exp(-np.pi*(x**2)/4)
```

Why this warning can appear if x is always given and it's numeric (sometimes it's a numpy array but it should work in any case..
Any suggestions?

Or maybe you can suggest how to catch that warning to log the issue in more details?

Comment: _sometimes it's a numpy array but it should work_, Erm, are you **sure** about that?  As far as I know, a "scalar" is absolutely supposed to be a **single numeric value**.  Not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular function performs [scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication), not matrix or vector multiplication. This means your input cannot be arrays or other iterables but should be scalar values.